CIFS VFS: Send error in read -9 -11
I keep getting these errors on a Linux client with Samba mounts.
kernel: [4372075.205159] CIFS VFS: Send error in read = -9
kernel: [4372421.609254] CIFS VFS: Error -11 sending data on socket to server

Logs are full with them but it does not cause any data loss or funcitonality issues.
I use the following parameters:
mount -t cifs -o username=$USER,password=$PASS,uid=1000,gid=1000,file_mode=0750,dir_mode=0750,iocharset=utf8,vers=2.1,netbiosname=namebox,noserverino //$HOST/

Some similar posts recommended using vers=2.1 doesn't make much difference for me.
Any suggestions?
